# Acquaintances Showing up in Facebook Ticker

Tags: facebook

I'm the sort of person who doesn't like to unfriend people on Facebook unless I actually dislike them, so I have quite a few friends that post stuff I really don't care about. Naturally, when I discovered that you can set people as acquaintances I went through my list acquaintancing people.

This worked quite well for a while, but recently the little ticker thing above the chat sidebar has been full of updates from acquaintances. My newsfeed is still only stuff I actually care about, but the ticker is about 70% stuff that doesn't interest me, so I want to see if I can get it back to how it was before.

Is this just how acquaintances work now, or is there something I can do to keep my acquaintances out of the ticker?